# Multiple regression - plot with 2 variables(log(t)+t) in r

Tags: r, plot, linear-regression

I run multiple regression with 6 variables.
My equation looks like:

```
sl~I(p^2)+p+I(-fi^2)+fi+log(t)+t
```

I would like to plot just a part responsible for "t" variable, but I have no idea how can I do that. Here are my coefficients:

```
Coefficients:
(Intercept)            p     I(-fi^2)       log(t)            t       I(p^2)           fi  
   575.9793     -14.4657     144.7662    -139.1052       0.4559       0.8622     299.7550
```

I know that I can create a function:

```
f=-139.1052*log(t)+0.4559*t+A
```

Where A is a number and I can manipulate with "A" to fit the data(plot(t,sl)), but it is not efficient and proffesional.

How can I plot a curve just using variables dependant from "t" while fitting my data?

I just want to use these variables:

```
log(t) and t
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to add back 'A' so that it equals the intercept plus the coefficients times the mean values for data referring to the other parameters in the model:

```
A.est <- 575.9793 -14.4657*mean(p) +144.7662*mean(-fi^2) +0.8622*mean(p^2) + 575.9793*mean(fi)
```

Then your estimated `sl` values will appear to be appropriate on the scale of your data.